# How to retrieve big data logs from cloud AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

how can I download aws lambda and sagemaker logs in my local system automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the company would have an account and allow departments to create resources like object storage buckets, databases, IAM roles, etc. that separate the data.

"Big Data" nor the cloud is required for this setup